# Can't install Appium on Linux using Linuxbrew due to "error status 1"

Tags: linux, appium, linuxbrew

For the last few days, I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/04/from-zero-to-appium-guide-configuring-appium-android/) on how to install Appium on Linux.

By the time I have executed the following command in the terminal:

```
./reset.sh —android --verbose
```

I keep on getting an error similar to this:

> error status number 1

I even went to the extent of executing the following command in the terminal:

```
./reset.sh --hardcore --verbose
```

The first time I executed the command above, I have got this notification:

> "reset.sh completed successfully"

However, underneath that notification, there was an error that has something to do with a missing Git.

Here are the things I have installed on my Linux machine, in terms of the **requirements** to run Appium:

- -Node.js - v9.9.0
- -NPM - 5.6.0
- -Maven - Apache Maven 3.3.9
- -Ant - Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6
- -Android API 19

Here are my **machine's specs**:

- intel 15 6400
- -ram ddr3 8gb
- -LInux Mint 18.1

Comment: What was the exact git error message? Have you installed git on your machine?

Comment: "there was an error that has something to do with a missing Git" -> you should install git then try again.